# hide/show clicking on another div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to hide/show list of elements when I click on button but it won't hide them and console.log of "shouldHide" is equal undefined.

function

```
showHideToggle(){
  this.setState({shouldHide: true});
}


    const { shouldHide} = this.props;
```

Div I want to hide

```
     <div className={shouldHide ? 'hidden' : ''} >
        <WeatherInfo />
    </div>;
```

this is the div which is separate from one I'm trying to hide

```
<div onClick={(e) => {this.List(e);this.showHideToggle}}></div>
```

constructor

```
this.state = {
  shouldHide: true
};
```

Comment: are you sure you're not trying to do `const { shouldHide} = this.state;` instead?

Comment: still getting undefined, even when i put this.state

Comment: have you defined state in your `constructor`? Maybe show that too

Comment: I forgot to put state in constructor. how should I now proced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor should look like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { shouldHide: true };
  }
```

and your showhide should probably do this instead otherwise it won't toggle and will always be true

```
showHideToggle(){
  this.setState({shouldHide: this.state.shouldHide ? false : true});
}
```

`const { shouldHide} = this.props;` should be `const { shouldHide} = this.state` in your render area

but `<div className={this.state.shouldHide ? 'hidden' : ''} >` should work as well given it's in the right area.

Comment: cool it's hiding it. Now for removing class just do the oposite?

Comment: if you click it again it should remove it, though I might be wrong :X But yeah just remove the class if that's how it works

Comment: nop it doesn't remove it now to remove class I need to rework it?

Comment: can you add a `console.log(this.state.shouldHide)` on the last line of `showHideToggle()`? and tell me what it prints when you click it each time (only twice is enough)

Comment: I think `this.setState({shouldHide: shouldHide ? false : true});` should be `this.setState({shouldHide: this.state.shouldHide ? false : true});` instead. Let me know if it changes anything